# Prevent Google App Engine from serving from appspot.com

Tags: java, google-app-engine, redirect, google-cloud-dns

I'm serving my app from a custom domain. I don't want it to be available at the appspot.com domain. What's the easiest way to achieve this? I'd like to be able to do it at the console level, but I have feeling I'll have to configure it in the app. The app is written in Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you want to completely deny any access via the appspot domain.

Use a custom `ServletFilter` to check the [`HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()) to see if it matches the `appspot.com` domain and return a `404 Not Found`.

The filters are applied in the order they are listed in the `web.xml` so make sure this one is the first one.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I did it in the doGet, but I'd imagine a filter would be more efficient.

Comment: that means you have to modify the `doGet()` in every servlet, and what about `Servlets` you do not have the source to?

Comment: Yes. You're right. The situation that I'm in is that I have an existing project written in GWT. It's going to be re-written from the ground up without GWT. So, to test the redirection, I just ran it on a simple very simple App. When I come to do the re-write, I'll most likely use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did something like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    if (req.getRequestURL().toString().startsWith ("http://1-dot-")) {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        resp.setHeader("Location", "[my custom domain]");
    }
}
```